# Is there a point in compensating for multiple frames/windows nowadays in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

In Douglas Crockford's book, he states that

```
if (my_value && typeof my_value === 'object' &&
        typeof my_value.length === 'number' &&
        !(my_value.propertyIsEnumerable('length')) {
    // my_value is truly an array!
}
```

is the best way to check if a variable is an array, because it compensates for variables in other frames or windows.

Should one still (in 2011) be coding for and around multiple frames and windows?

Comment: `iframe` is in the html5 spec so  I don't see why not.  Though most libraries abstract away this code anyways so the average joe could care less either way.

Comment: That code could technically give false positives in modern browsers. http://jsfiddle.net/RVkNR/1/ A safer way is to use `Object.prototype.toString.call( my_value ) === '[object Array]'`.

Comment: @patrick: That [doesn't work](http://tobyho.com/Checking_Types_in_Javascript) across different windows in IE. Also it is technically possible to overwrite `Object.prototype.toString`...

Comment: @Pumbaa80: Yes it is possible to overwrite it, but the solution to that is simple, remove the offending code and yell profanities at the developer who overwrote it. Good point about popup windows though. Looks like the issue still exists in IE9!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. `<iframe>` elements are still very much part of web development today and for the foreseeable future.

However, if your page or application is guaranteed never to use iframes, you can omit the checks recommended by Crockford, perhaps with comments in the code to draw attention to the fact you're doing so.

Answer (score 1):

`iframe` elements aren't the only way of getting multiple context scripts. A simple call to `window.open` will produce a new window context. Popups tend to be less common now-a-days, but they are still readily available in good UI designs.

Take Gmail for instance, not only are `iframes` used all over the place, but you can also pop out your message and chat windows to have a separate window to move around. If you're creating a plugin that relies on this functionality, you'd be better off sticking to the tried-and-true method.

Answer (score 0):

What book and what print?

I have some experience with the nastiness of arrays that aren't really arrays in JavaScript. Such as: `select.options` (the options property of a `<select>` element) and `arguments` (the magic variable). I don't know if these pass the test you mention but I'm very much afraid they will.

Knowing whether something is an array isn't very useful by itself. You likely want to know if you can iterate over it, or if it has a `length` property or a `slice` function for instance.

So I guess it's a bit of a moot point, but I'd be interested to see what anyone else can come up with.

As for frames, as I've outlined, I don't think frames are your biggest concern. I don't really see what frames have to do with arrays, unless they also contain a similar *gotcha*

Comment: Javascript: The Good Parts. (I always thought that was his only book...)

Comment: @Frits: *"Knowing whether something is an array isn't very useful by itself."* It is very useful information as it will answer many questions as to what methods it has, what they do, and how its `.length` property behaves. Frames can be a concern when duck typing because they can lead to unexpected results when doing an `instanceof` test or a `.constructor` comparison.

Comment: The deal with iframes is all about checking by the "constructor" property. If you get some "alien" JavaScript references from a separate page, then even if something really is an Array instance, a test against its "constructor" in a different page will fail, because each page has its own "Array" constructor!

Comment: @patrick dw, You completely missed my point. The outlined check probably still succeeds for the cases that I mentioned. It is impossible to determine if something is an array in JavaScript, you can only look at it and see that it behaves like an array (like duck typing). Similarly, you don't really care whether it's an array, you just want to know if it has a `slice` function or a `push` function.

Comment: Frits: I understood your point, but if the object has a `.slice()` function, that doesn't mean it will do what you want it to do. A String has `.slice()` too. Same with the `.length` property. String has it, but it doesn't behave the same as an Array's `.length`. That's where it is beneficial to know if you actually have an Array, and it isn't impossible. You can check the internal *[[Class]]* property using the method I noted in the comment below the answer. @Pointy: Yes, that's the unexpected result I was talking about. It affects `instanceof` as well.